# Pure CSS3 or SVG animated Doughnut Chart

Tags: html, css, svg, charts

I am looking for a pure CSS3 or SVG animated doughnut chart.

- Need to have the middle circle fill colour
- the outer circle to be split with a grey and a blue ie: blue 80% complete, grey 20% left remaining.
- need text in the middle of the circle.

I have found one example http://jsfiddle.net/4azpfk3r/

Can anyone help creating / editing the above to what i need please? Its half way there.

```
<div class="item css">
   <h2>CSS</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
     <title>Layer 1</title>
       <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#69aff4" fill="none"/>
      </g>
   </svg>
 </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: But what is your question?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this, it uses `stroke-dasharray` to create strokes with a length of 251.2 see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) for more reference . The stroke-dashoffset attribute specifies the distance into the dash pattern to start the dash [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset)

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="tomato"/>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="grey"/>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#00CCFF" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="50.3"/>
    <text x="40" y="50" fill="black" font-size="10">Text</text>
</svg>
```

Here the stroke fills 80% (calculated using 251.2 - 251.2*80/100, 251.2 is the perimeter of the circle calculated using 2 * 3.14 * 40). ie `stroke-dashoffset = perimeter - perimeter * amount / 100` also set `stroke-dasharray` to `perimeter`. `perimeter = 2 * 3.14 * radius`.

You can check **[this blog post](https://www.akzhy.com/blog/create-animated-donut-chart-using-svg-and-javascript/)** that explains the creation of doughnut charts easily.

See a 50% filled circle

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="tomato"/>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="grey"/>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#00CCFF" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="125.6"/>
    <text x="40" y="50" fill="black" font-size="10">Text</text>
</svg>
```

Demo with multiple rings :

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <!-- Center color -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="#eee"/>
    <!-- Default color of ring -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="grey"/>
    
    <!-- Progress -->
    <!-- The amount shown as 'filled' is the amount the ring fills, starting from right center (3 o' clock) -->
    <!-- 100% fill -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#2196f3" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
    <!-- 80% fill -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#ff5722" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="50.3"/>
    <!-- 70% filled -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#009688" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="75.36"/>
    <!-- 50% filled -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#9c27b0" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="125.6"/>
    <!-- 40% filled -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#e91e63" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="150.72"/>
    <!-- 20% filled -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#f44336" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="200.96"/>
    <!-- Center Text -->
    <text x="40" y="50" fill="black" font-size="10">Text</text>
</svg>
```

Demo with animation (not tested in all browsers)

```js
$(".progress").each(function() {
  var dataProgress = $(this).attr("stroke-dashoffset");
  $(this).attr("stroke-dashoffset", "251.2");
  $(this).animate({
    "stroke-dashoffset": dataProgress
  },1500)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <!-- Center color -->
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="#eee"/>
        <!-- Default color of ring -->
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="white"/>
        
        <!-- Progress -->
        <!-- The amount shown as 'filled' is the amount the ring fills, starting from right center (3 o' clock) -->
        <!-- 100% fill -->
        <circle class="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#2196f3" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
        <!-- 80% fill -->
        <circle class="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#ff5722" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="50.3"/>
        <!-- 70% filled -->
        <circle class="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#009688" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="75.36"/>
        <!-- 50% filled -->
        <circle class="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#9c27b0" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="125.6"/>
        <!-- 40% filled -->
        <circle class="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#e91e63" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="150.72"/>
        <!-- 20% filled -->
        <circle class="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#f44336" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="200.96"/>
        <!-- Center Text -->
        <text x="40" y="50" fill="black" font-size="10">Text</text>
    </svg>
```

Solution using jquery :

Give `data-fill=amount` to each of the `.progress` and jquery will do the rest

```js
var radius = parseInt($("#radius").attr("r")) // Get the radius of the circle 
var perimeter = 2 * 3.14 * radius;

$(".progress").each(function(){
  var amount = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-fill"));
  var fillAmount = perimeter - perimeter * amount / 100;
  
  $(this).attr({
    "stroke-dasharray":perimeter,
    "stroke-dashoffset":fillAmount
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <!-- Center color -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="#eee" id="radius"/>
    <!-- Default color of ring -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="grey"/>
    
    <!-- Progress -->
    <!-- The amount shown as 'filled' is the amount the ring fills, starting from right center (3 o' clock) -->
    <!-- 100% fill -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#2196f3" data-fill="100" class="progress"/>
    <!-- 80% fill -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#ff5722" data-fill="80" class="progress"/>
    <!-- 70% filled -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#009688" data-fill="70" class="progress"/>
    <!-- 50% filled -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#9c27b0" data-fill="50" class="progress"/>
    <!-- 40% filled -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#e91e63" data-fill="40" class="progress"/>
    <!-- 20% filled -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke-width="20" stroke="#f44336" data-fill="20" class="progress"/>
    <!-- Center Text -->
    <text x="40" y="50" fill="black" font-size="10">Text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: would be great if you could explain this a little bit more. I'm trying to figure out how the hell `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` interact with and influence each other.

Comment: @Akshay still doesn't make sense to me why you chose stroke-dasharray to ="251.2" why did you choose this number. Why did you make the stroke-dashoffset to 80%

Maybe there is some kind of ratio that is not obvious to me that you are using?

Comment: @mibbit Should have explained it better, i have updated my answer if you still don't get it feel free to comment, I know i am bad at explaining things

Comment: I still don't get your answer.
Anyone here can write more detail?
There are many confuse number.

Comment: @NguyễnAnhTuấn 125.6 -> `251.2 - 251.2*50/100` `251.2` is the perimeter of the circle and `50` is the amount to be filled

Comment: @Akshay Thank you.
I totally get it.

Comment: @Akshay, how do I make the doughnut section (grey part) start from the very top part and the if I want to specify 25% (or any amount) for grey part then the part falls in clockwise direction i.e. to the right? Currently it starts from middle of the right section.

Comment: @Aditya Sorry for the delay in response, I am not sure which snippet you meant but if you check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/754u9mpf/6/) You will see that the grey part animates from the top to 80% in clockwise direction. The trick is to rotate the circle -90deg so that the start point changes to the top.